# Finding line that each n value is on

Tags: plotting

This code produces straight lines, I'd like to find which n values are on which of the lines:

```
ListPlot[Differences[
  Table[PrimePi[Min[Prime[n + 1]^2, Product[Prime@i, {i, n}]]] - 
    n, {n, 3000}]]]
```

[image]

Is there a way to sort the n values accurately for a general case of multiple straight or curved lines?

cheers,
Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angles of the points capture rather well their belonging to one line or another. Combine that with Mathematica's clustering algorithms and you have a possible way of solving this:

```
data = Differences[Table[PrimePi[Min[Prime[n + 1]^2, Product[Prime@i, {i, n}]]] - n, {n, 3000}]];
pts = Transpose[{Range@Length[data], data}];
angles = ArcTan @@@ pts;
clusters = FindClusters[angles -> pts, Method -> "Agglomerate"];
ListPlot[clusters]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]